# What to do when I get "ACTIVE PQ RECORD REQUIRED" message in AirTicketRS

Tags: api, sabre

I tried to make a reservation from Sabre API by using this flow: 
Booking flow:
- SessionCreate 
- OTA_AirBookLLSService 
- OTA_AirPriceLLSService 
- PassengerDetails 
- Endtransaction 
- CloseSession 

Issue flow: 
- SessionCreate
- GetReservation
- DesignatePrinter
- AirTicket
- CloseSession

When I perform AirTicket, I get this response:

```xml
<ns2:AirTicketRS Version="2.12.0" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
    <ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
        <Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-08-26T22:31:45-05:00">
            <SystemSpecificResults>
                <Message>ACTIVE PQ RECORD REQUIRED-1074</Message>
                <ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</ShortText>
            </SystemSpecificResults>
         </Error>
    </ApplicationResults>
</ns2:AirTicketRS>
```

**Does anyone know why I get this message? How to fix it?**

---

OTA_AirBookRQ:

```xml
<OTA_AirBookRQ Version="2.1.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
    <OriginDestinationInformation>
        <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2019-11-17T08:10" DepartureDateTime="2019-11-17T06:00" FlightNumber="209" NumberInParty="3" ResBookDesigCode="M" Status="NN">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="SGN"/>
            <Equipment AirEquipType="350"/>
            <MarketingAirline Code="VN" FlightNumber="209"/>
            <OperatingAirline Code="VN"/>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="HAN"/>
        </FlightSegment>
        <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2019-11-27T07:35" DepartureDateTime="2019-11-27T05:30" FlightNumber="4928" NumberInParty="3" ResBookDesigCode="M" Status="NN">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="HAN"/>
            <Equipment AirEquipType="320"/>
            <MarketingAirline Code="VN" FlightNumber="4928"/>
            <OperatingAirline Code="VN"/>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="SGN"/>
        </FlightSegment>
    </OriginDestinationInformation>
</OTA_AirBookRQ>
```

OTA_AirPriceRQ:

```xml
<OTA_AirPriceRQ Version="2.17.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
  <PriceRequestInformation Retain="true">
    <OptionalQualifiers>
      <PricingQualifiers>
        <FareOptions Private="false"/>
        <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="2"/>
        <PassengerType Code="CNN" Quantity="1"/>
        <PassengerType Code="INF" Quantity="1"/>
      </PricingQualifiers>
    </OptionalQualifiers>
  </PriceRequestInformation>
</OTA_AirPriceRQ>
```

---

**PassengerDetailsRQ and PassengerDetailsRS**

```xml
<ns8:PassengerDetailsRQ version="3.3.0" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns8="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3" xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns3="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
  <ns8:PriceQuoteInfo>
    <ns8:Link HostedCarrier="true" NameNumber="1.1" Record="1"/>
    <ns8:Link HostedCarrier="true" NameNumber="2.1" Record="1"/>
    <ns8:Link HostedCarrier="true" NameNumber="3.1" Record="2"/>
    <ns8:Link HostedCarrier="true" NameNumber="4.1" Record="3"/>
  </ns8:PriceQuoteInfo>
  <ns8:SpecialReqDetails>
    <ns8:SpecialServiceRQ>
      <ns8:SpecialServiceInfo>
        <ns8:AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="0">
          <ns8:Document ExpirationDate="2024-10-11" Number="816690357" Type="P">
            <ns8:IssueCountry>VN</ns8:IssueCountry>
            <ns8:NationalityCountry>VN</ns8:NationalityCountry>
          </ns8:Document>
          <ns8:PersonName DateOfBirth="2000-10-11" DocumentHolder="true" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
            <ns8:GivenName>EQM</ns8:GivenName>
            <ns8:Surname>MDS</ns8:Surname>
          </ns8:PersonName>
        </ns8:AdvancePassenger>
        <ns8:AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="0">
          <ns8:Document ExpirationDate="2024-10-11" Number="047925947" Type="P">
            <ns8:IssueCountry>VN</ns8:IssueCountry>
            <ns8:NationalityCountry>VN</ns8:NationalityCountry>
          </ns8:Document>
          <ns8:PersonName DateOfBirth="2000-10-11" DocumentHolder="true" Gender="F" NameNumber="2.1">
            <ns8:GivenName>DSQ</ns8:GivenName>
            <ns8:Surname>TBV</ns8:Surname>
          </ns8:PersonName>
        </ns8:AdvancePassenger>
        <ns8:AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="0">
          <ns8:Document ExpirationDate="2024-10-11" Number="187782854" Type="P">
            <ns8:IssueCountry>VN</ns8:IssueCountry>
            <ns8:NationalityCountry>VN</ns8:NationalityCountry>
          </ns8:Document>
          <ns8:PersonName DateOfBirth="2012-10-11" DocumentHolder="true" Gender="F" NameNumber="3.1">
            <ns8:GivenName>YGO</ns8:GivenName>
            <ns8:Surname>TWR</ns8:Surname>
          </ns8:PersonName>
        </ns8:AdvancePassenger>
        <ns8:AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="0">
          <ns8:Document ExpirationDate="2024-10-11" Number="049011759" Type="P">
            <ns8:IssueCountry>VN</ns8:IssueCountry>
            <ns8:NationalityCountry>VN</ns8:NationalityCountry>
          </ns8:Document>
          <ns8:PersonName DateOfBirth="2018-10-11" DocumentHolder="true" Gender="F" NameNumber="1.1">
            <ns8:GivenName>RSR</ns8:GivenName>
            <ns8:Surname>HDW</ns8:Surname>
          </ns8:PersonName>
        </ns8:AdvancePassenger>
        <ns8:SecureFlight SegmentNumber="1">
          <ns8:PersonName DateOfBirth="2012-10-11" Gender="F" NameNumber="3.1">
            <ns8:GivenName>YGO MISS</ns8:GivenName>
            <ns8:Surname>TWR</ns8:Surname>
          </ns8:PersonName>
        </ns8:SecureFlight>
        <ns8:SecureFlight SegmentNumber="1">
          <ns8:PersonName DateOfBirth="2018-10-11" Gender="F" NameNumber="4.1">
            <ns8:GivenName>RSR MISS</ns8:GivenName>
            <ns8:Surname>HDW</ns8:Surname>
          </ns8:PersonName>
        </ns8:SecureFlight>
        <ns8:Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="CHLD">
          <ns8:PersonName NameNumber="3.1"/>
          <ns8:Text>11OCT12</ns8:Text>
          <ns8:VendorPrefs>
            <ns8:Airline Hosted="true"/>
          </ns8:VendorPrefs>
        </ns8:Service>
        <ns8:Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="INFT">
          <ns8:PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
          <ns8:Text>HDW/RSR MISS/11OCT18</ns8:Text>
          <ns8:VendorPrefs>
            <ns8:Airline Hosted="true"/>
          </ns8:VendorPrefs>
        </ns8:Service>
      </ns8:SpecialServiceInfo>
    </ns8:SpecialServiceRQ>
  </ns8:SpecialReqDetails>
  <ns8:TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
    <ns8:AgencyInfo>
      <ns8:Address>
        <ns8:AddressLine>11Bis Nguyen Gia Thieu</ns8:AddressLine>
        <ns8:CityName>Ho Chi Minh</ns8:CityName>
        <ns8:CountryCode>VN</ns8:CountryCode>
        <ns8:PostalCode>700000    </ns8:PostalCode>
        <ns8:StreetNmbr>11Bis Nguyen Gia Thieu</ns8:StreetNmbr>
        <ns8:VendorPrefs>
          <ns8:Airline Hosted="true"/>
        </ns8:VendorPrefs>
      </ns8:Address>
      <ns8:Ticketing TicketType="8TL30"/>
    </ns8:AgencyInfo>
    <ns8:CustomerInfo>
      <ns8:ContactNumbers>
        <ns8:ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="0916 150 850" PhoneUseType="B"/>
      </ns8:ContactNumbers>
      <ns8:Email Address="system@gotadi.com" NameNumber="1.1"/>
      <ns8:PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT">
        <ns8:GivenName>EQM MR</ns8:GivenName>
        <ns8:Surname>MDS</ns8:Surname>
      </ns8:PersonName>
      <ns8:PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="2.1" PassengerType="ADT">
        <ns8:GivenName>DSQ MS</ns8:GivenName>
        <ns8:Surname>TBV</ns8:Surname>
      </ns8:PersonName>
      <ns8:PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="3.1" PassengerType="CNN">
        <ns8:GivenName>YGO MISS</ns8:GivenName>
        <ns8:Surname>TWR</ns8:Surname>
      </ns8:PersonName>
      <ns8:PersonName Infant="true" NameNumber="4.1" PassengerType="INF">
        <ns8:GivenName>RSR MISS</ns8:GivenName>
        <ns8:Surname>HDW</ns8:Surname>
      </ns8:PersonName>
    </ns8:CustomerInfo>
  </ns8:TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</ns8:PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:PassengerDetailsRS xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns8="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" xmlns:ns7="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns3="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
  <ns8:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
    <ns8:Success timeStamp="2019-10-10T20:56:15.245-05:00"/>
    <ns8:Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-10-10T20:56:14.821-05:00">
      <ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
        <ns8:Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">.INVALID ACTION</ns8:Message>
      </ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
    </ns8:Warning>
    <ns8:Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-10-10T20:56:14.986-05:00">
      <ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
        <ns8:Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">?SEGMENT NUMBER NOT VALID?</ns8:Message>
      </ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
    </ns8:Warning>
    <ns8:Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-10-10T20:56:15.089-05:00">
      <ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
        <ns8:Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">Â?INVALID PRICING RECORD NUMBER-0062Â?</ns8:Message>
      </ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
    </ns8:Warning>
    <ns8:Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-10-10T20:56:15.127-05:00">
      <ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
        <ns8:Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">Â?INVALID PRICING RECORD NUMBER-0062Â?</ns8:Message>
      </ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
    </ns8:Warning>
    <ns8:Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-10-10T20:56:15.176-05:00">
      <ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
        <ns8:Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">Â?INVALID PRICING RECORD NUMBER-0062Â?</ns8:Message>
      </ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
    </ns8:Warning>
    <ns8:Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-10-10T20:56:15.243-05:00">
      <ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
        <ns8:Message code="WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR">Â?INVALID PRICING RECORD NUMBER-0062Â?</ns8:Message>
      </ns8:SystemSpecificResults>
    </ns8:Warning>
  </ns8:ApplicationResults>
</ns2:PassengerDetailsRS>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would you mind to share your RQs from OTA_AirBookLLSService and OTA_AirPriceLLSService, because the root cause can be the class you are using to sell is different from the class you are using to pricing or you are not associating the segments in a correct way.

Comment: I 've added RQs from OTA_AirBookLLSService and OTA_AirPriceLLSService.

Comment: When you perform the PassengerDetailsRQ what is the Response, because apparently you are getting a problem there, I saw you have an infant in your reservation. Would you mind to share it (PassengerDetailsRQ, RS), another point, are you using SabreCommand(ER) to perform endtransaction, if yes, what is the message returned ?

Comment: I 've added PassengerDetails RQ and RS.

Comment: You are getting problem in your PassengerDetailsRQ take a look the response (SEGMENT NUMBER NOT VALID), (INVALID PRICING RECORD NUMBER) Sabre is warning you that something is WRONG. First of all you have to fix the PassengerDetailsRQ in this step you are recording the PQ, take a look the segment number in your request, there is no segment with number 0 (ZERO) SegmentNumber="0" you have to start counting from 1.

Comment: What about these messages: INVALID ACTION, INVALID PRICING RECORD NUMBER. Thank you for your support.

Comment: First fix the segment number and try it once again, maybe this message will disappear.

Comment: I fixed the segment number and the message disappeared. But these warning messages still remain: CHECK ITINERARY, INVALID PRICING RECORD NUMBER, INVALID ACTION.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities as to why no Price Quote (PQ) is present in the described workflow.

a) you are not retaining the Price Quote

or

b) you are not linking the Price Quote to the corrosponding segments

Comment: Could you please tell me more details about this way:
b) you are not linking the Price Quote to the corresponding segments
@Thomas

Comment: Can you post your PassengerdetailsRQ?

Comment: I 've added PassengerDetails RQ and RS.